Why is the term "castle" now synonymous with "palace" and "mansion", even when the latter two lack the architectural features of medieval castles?
The term "castle" sometimes is applied to dwellings that bear no resemblance to the real medieval castles. Why is that? It sometimes appears in the official names of specific residences, like Hearst Castle, and other times, residences are sometimes referred to as 'castles' even when they're built in architectural styles like baroque. It has even morphed into the phrase "man's home is his castle"!

Hearst Castle is formally known as La Cuesta Encantada, so maybe someone thought "cuesta" meant "castle" (it means "hill")? Do you have any other examples that you don't consider to be castles? People certainly have the freedom to call things "castle" even if they're not castles. But there are building styles that maybe you don't think of as castles but which are defensive in nature, like the Scottish tower house. Do you know what "a man's home is his castle" means, because castle means stronghold/fortification in that saying?

There's a huge variation in "real medieval castles" in terms of design and construction around the world and across the thousand years of the medieval period, so it would be difficult to exclude any resemblance to any real medieval castle.

'Hurst Castle' sounds better than 'Hurst Hall' or 'Hurst House'.

The Online Etymology Dictionary claims that 'castle' originally meant 'village' (in Late Old English), so perhaps a better question would be 'how did it come to be applied to a fortress?' Doubtless because some settlements were walled, fortified. But research is needed. // One of the largest (if not the largest) of the castles in Wales is Penrhyn Castle, a Victorian mock castle. People will have their fantasies, some going way beyond just playing with words.

Not an answer, but word meanings are just not as immutable or precise as we'd like to think.

Um, "A man's home is his castle" is a good example of metaphor. Therefore we literally don't take it literally: Wherever they live, folks luxuriate with a feeling of grandeur.


Why is the term "castle" now synonymous with "palace" and "mansion",

This is a false assumption:

"He owns a mansion in Scotland" and "The King lives in Buckingham Palace" do not imply that the mansion/palace is a castle.

Not all castles are stereotypical.



even when the latter two lack the architectural features of medieval castles?

Not all castles are medieval. The term "Castle" is also applied to Roman and pre-Roman earthworks.
OED

Castle
II. From French.
II.3.a. A large building or set of buildings fortified for defence
against an enemy; a fortress, stronghold. Retained as a name for
large mansions or country houses, which were formerly feudal castles,
but not, like French château, transferred to this sense.


Yes, a transferred meaning sums it up.
